# Crystal Report dynamic location

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I want that my crystal report, if the project is moved to another folder, keeps working without changing the code. Thats the code right now in my WinForm

```
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
cryRpt.Load(@"Z:\Tempesta\Area Progetto\Area_Progetto_13_03_2014\Area_Progetto_27_02_2014\Area_Progetto_DATA_MAGAZINE\Data_Magazine\Data_Magazine\CrystalReport1.rpt");
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible, if you don't want to change your code behind just write the path in a `.txt` file and read it when you open your crystal report.
And if the path changes just change the path value in the `.txt` file.

Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If the report is stored in a location relative to the application then you can use `Environment.CurrentDirectory` to generate a path.

```
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
string reportPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "CrystalReport1.rpt");
cryRpt.Load(reportPath);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Comment: It says that Path doesnt exist in the contest.

Comment: You'll need to import the System.IO namespace or change Path to System.IO.Path